# Use of the word "solve"?

Tags: integration, terminology

This is not a mathematical question, but just a matter of terminology.

I don't understand why so many people (especially on MSE) want to *solve* integrals. It makes sense for me (linguistically speaking) to solve an equation or to solve a problem, but definitely not to solve an integral: instead, I would just say *compute*.

So, I would like to know if "to solve an integral" is correct English. Needless to say, English is not my native language...

Comment: In math a lot of things can be re-written in equation form. I would agree that you aren't strictly solving anything when you integrate $\int f(x) \,dx$ but that is equivalent to "solving" the equation $F(x) = \int f(x)\, dx$ for $F(x)$.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, but I don't think 'solve' is an appropriate term for what you describe. I think the confusion comes from misconception of the terms (solve, compute and variants) themselves and possibly from the fact (?) that in some languages the natural translation of 'solve' leads to the concept of 'compute' in english. There's also the possibility that you could look at it as "Solve the problem" and the problem actually is an integral.

Comment: Another French asking the same question  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9060/solve-compute-evaluate-when-should-we-use-these-verbs

Comment: @brad You remind me of the basket-weaver who told me all mathematical problems reduce to basket weaving. After all, if the solution to your problem is $X$, then a basket in the shape of $X$ is the solution to your problem.

Comment: @G.T.R Thanks for the link. I should have checked before.

Comment: Related: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2288/996

Comment: @200_success Thanks as well for this link.

Comment: @SergioParreiras It sounds strange to me...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "solve an integral".  It may be imprecise, but English is not a particularly precise language.

Comment: I've had a few more years experience with primary school math instruction (via my kids) than when I first asked the linked question, and I've noticed that a lot of teachers use the verb *solve* for any math problem.  As in “Solve $148 \div 4$.”  I also see calculus students use *solve* for limits.  So I am guessing teachers are transferring to students the notion that every question that can be asked in math is a problem to be “solved” in some way.  Call me stuffy, but I think this is too broad a brush.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I think I agree with you...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is wrong in English to say "solve an integral". We should say "evaluate an integral" or "compute an integral" instead.

Comment: I forgot "evaluate"... thanks!

Comment: I tend to think that "compute" applies only to definite integrals, but that may just be me. "Evaluate" seems like the correct choice for finding a non-integral expression of an integral.

Answer (score 10):

In the Russian it is not correct. Russians use word 'take' instead.

Comment: That's interesting! In French we would never say "take".

Comment: oddly enough, in English we "take" derivatives but not integrals....

Comment: Indeed, see e.g. [this](http://dxdy.ru/post836965.html?sid=34c513d51e52371c3886da242650324a#p836965) message on a Russian forum: "Решить интеграл - невозможно!", i.e. "It is impossible to solve an integral". This hints to the frequent use of this incorrect term by Russian students (and I have heard really many of them say so). Usually they are those who just want to pass the math class and never return to it.